# Checking the size of received data in Axis2 web services

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

Is there any way of enforcing a maximum size for data received from the client, in an Axis2 Java web service?

This would be needed, for example, in order to protect from flooding attacks against the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't sound like something you would want to enforce in Axis, but in the server. For instance, in Tomcat, you can set the `maxPostSize` of the HttpConnector:

> The maximum size in bytes of the POST which will be handled by the
>   container FORM URL parameter parsing. The limit can be disabled by
>   setting this attribute to a value less than or equal to 0. If not
>   specified, this attribute is set to 2097152 (2 megabytes).

See [Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html)

For Jetty, the maxFormContentSize is used:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="maxFormContentSize">200000</Set>
</Configure>
```

And you can set this for a single webapp or for the entire server, according to [Jetty/Howto/Configure Form Size](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Form_Size).

Comment: Thanks. This is were I would expect it to happen. Do you happen to know the setting for Jetty, as well?

Comment: Added configuration for jetty as well.